# Can Apache Proxy Websockets for Rstudio's Shiny?

Tags: r, apache, proxy, websocket, shiny

Websockets can be faster than plain HTTP(s) requests and browsers can usually open more websocket connections.

My browser is telling me via the javascript console  that while my shiny app works and apache proxypass is proxying correctly, websockets aren't working:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.example.com/shiny/01_hello/__sockjs__/058/v193lng7/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I've seen different ways that Apache can be configured to proxy websockets. Such as:

```
    ProxyPass /shiny/  ws://127.0.0.1:3838/
    ProxyPass /shiny/ wss://127.0.0.1:3838/
    RedirectMatch ^/shiny$ /shiny/
```

and:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3001/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
```

My question is, can any of these be adapted for use with shiny?

Comment: I have a related problem. Using the apache proxy my shiny apps are quasi systemtically disconnected, and I see "RobustSockJS collision" messages in the shiny server log. Adding websocket proxypass or/and proxypassreverse for ws: does improve.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your R file is handeling Websockets badly.

In your HTML file in your java script, you have something like:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://"+hostlocation, "HelloR")
```

And then the following functions which you define as you need:

```
socket.onopen = function() {}
socket.onmessage = function got_packet(msg) {}
socket.onclose = function(){}
```

And in your R code you have something something like:

```
w = create_server(webpage=static_text_service(htmldata))
f = function(DATA,WS,...)
{
list(msg,p)= process(data)
websocket_broadcast(toJSON(list(msg=msg, fig=p)),WS$server)
}
set_callback("receive",f,w)
ctmp = tempfile()
itmp = tempfile()
daemonize(w)
```

Where htmldata is your html file.

Then modify the httpd.conf to have:

```
<VirtualHost *:origin_port>
  ProxyPass /shiny/  ws://127.0.0.1:3838/
  ProxyPassReverse /shiny/  ws://127.0.0.1:3838/
</VirtualHost>
```

where origin_port is the port number of origin and ws://127.0.0.1:3838/ is the address and port of the host.

Make sure you are not missing any of these critical parts. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however Websockets are fully functional when connecting directly to Shiny-server. When Shiny-server is proxied using Apache, the Websockets are not proxied correctly.

Comment: Try ProxyPass, but also add a 
ProxyPassReverse /shiny/  ws://127.0.0.1:3838/
I think that that might be the problem.

Comment: I added a section for proxy forwarding. Hopefully it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the try, however adding the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse as suggested did not correctly proxy the websockets. I think it would probably be best if someone with access to shiny-server would confirm locally if it works first before posting an answer.